# Theme for all of salesforce pages

Tags: css

I have been tasked with modifying our salesforce page to look like our company's theme, but it seems like Visualforce is the only way and that I have to create one for each page that exists within Salesforce.

I have looked high and low and so far there doesn't appear to be a way to easily change the color for exmaple... so as a last effort I would like to ask you experts here, is there really no way to change the theme (eg. background color/font/font color) from a single place? may be I'm just searching with the wrong terms.

I found this
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdNJwzhok_M

but it doesn't seem to work anymore as the show html box checkbox is missing (the tutorial is from 2011), could this be hidden somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce fairly recently blocked the ability for sidebar components to hijack the standard styles/execute JavaScript, etc. As such, modifying the "theme" is largely impossible these days. My understanding is that eventually a "custom theme" system might be available for salesforce (right now, we have "Theme1" and "Theme2", two standard themes). Unfortunately, nobody seems to know when this might happen.

Comment: thanks, guess i'm going to have fun creating visualforce pages

Comment: For now, I guess you'd call it job security.